# django email authentication

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

## userform

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(label="Confirm Password",widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Confirm Password','class':'required'}))    
    phone =    forms.CharField(max_length = 15,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder':'Enter mobile no. ','class':'required number'}))
    profession = forms.CharField(max_length= 50,widget = forms.Select(choices = PROFESSION_CHOICES,attrs = {'class':'required'}))

    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email address',max_length = 75,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter a valid email.','class':'required email'}))
    sex = forms.CharField(max_length = 20,label="I am :",widget=forms.Select(choices=SEX_CHOICES,attrs = {'class':'required'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password",widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Password','class':'required'})) 
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Please enter your real name.','class':'required alphabets'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter last name.','class':'required alphabets'}))
    def clean_first_name(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        if first_name == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
    def clean_phone(self):
        phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
        if phone == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")

    def clean_last_name(self):
        last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        if last_name == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        try:
            user  = User.objects.get(email = email)
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email already in use.")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
    def clean_profession(self):
        profession = self.cleaned_data['profession']
        if profession == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError("Select a valid option.")

    def clean_sex(self):
        sex = self.cleaned_data['sex']
        if sex == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError("Select a valid option.")

    def save(self,*args,**kw):
        user = super(UserForm,self).save(*args,**kw)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data.get("password"))
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
        user.email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        user.save()
        user.get_profile().phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        user.get_profile().location = self.cleaned_data.get('location')
        user.get_profile().profession = self.cleaned_data.get('profession')
        user.get_profile().sex = self.cleaned_data.get('sex')
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password','confirm_password','first_name','last_name','sex','phone','profession')
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
```

## user registration view

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.POST:
        data = request.POST.copy()

        data["username"] = 'user'
        rform = UserForm(data)
        #form = UserProfileForm()
        if rform.is_valid():
            try:
                user = rform.save()
                user.username = "user"+str(user.id)
                user.save()
                user = authenticate(username = user.username,password=user.password)
                #register user
                login(request,user)
                return redirect(index)
            except:
                print "Unexpected error"
                raise
        else:
        # submit the same form again.
            form = LoginForm();
            sform = LoginForm()
            return render_to_response('register.html',{'rform':rform,'form':form,'sform':sform},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    else:
        rform  = UserForm()
        #form = UserProfileForm()
        form = LoginForm()
        sform = LoginForm()
        return render_to_response('register.html',{'rform':rform,'form':form,'sform':sform},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

## error

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/register/
auth_user.first_name may not be NULL
```

## doubt

When i was using the normal user authentication , everything was working perfectly but when i am using it with email authentication , it gives me the above error ,
how do i get past this error , please help , and also how do i make the email field unique as in how do i add index to this field , please help

Comment: This means the field "first_name" of the model "auth_user" can not stor NULL values. So you need to make sure, you are passing a correct value & datatype for that field or customize the model to accept Null values like first_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=20, null=True)

Comment: Try username = request.POST['username']

Comment: Please try to explain what you're asking. The title implies a connection to email authentication, which I see nowhere.
What is the reasons for the clean_$field methods? Django fields are required by default.
What is the reasons for the two LoginForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom field cleaning methods (`clean_*`) do not return the cleaned value. From the form validation docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/

> Just like the
>   general field clean() method, above, this method should return the
>   cleaned data, regardless of whether it changed anything or not.

`clean_first_name` does not have a return which is the same as returning `None` and the reason why Django is trying to insert a `NULL` for this field.

Comment: but now i am getting
 AttributeError at /accounts/register/
'User' object has no attribute 'backend'

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your `authenticate` or `login` call but comments aren't a good place for a stacktrace. This should be a different question.